# Removing code duplication in an identical public methods of 2 not related classes

Tags: java, code-duplication

I have 2 different classes which contain considerable number of the same public methods.

```
public class HorizontalPackageSelector extends HorizontalScrollView {

    // skipped

    public void method1() {
        doSomething1();
        doSomething2();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class VerticalPackageSelector extends ScrollView {

    // skipped

    public void method1() {
        doSomething1();
        doSomething2();
    }

}
```

And several other methods (about 200 lines in both classes).

I see only one way to avoid duplication:

```
public class PackageSelectorHelper {

    // skipped

    public void method1() {
        doSomething1();
        doSomething2();
    }

}

public class HorizontalPackageSelector extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private final PackageSelectorHelper helper = new PackageSelectorHelper(this);

    // skipped

    public void method1() {
        helper.method1();
    }

}

public class VerticalPackageSelector extends ScrollView {

    private final PackageSelectorHelper helper = new PackageSelectorHelper(this);

    // skipped

    public void method1() {
        helper.method1();
    }

}
```

But this is not easy to do if a number of identical methods is too big.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the context and how you use these classes. I wonder if you really need to extend HorizontalScrollView (ScrollView). Maybe you can create a class PackageSelector with method1, ... that has a an additional member of type FrameLayout (which would then hold the HorizontalScrollView or ScrollView).

Comment: If `HorizontalScrollView` extends `ScrollView`, could you put the method in `ScrollView`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. They have the same parent class - `FrameLayout`

Comment: Your solution looks good to me.  Refactoring often isn't easy ... but as large as the effort is, at least it's an effort that will only have to be done once.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class and make your class extend from that class
or you can make methods static- don't exactly know the implementation in method

Comment: I think the problem with your solution is that the original classes already extend a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface AProb{
  public void method1();
  public void method2();
  public void method3();
}

Class aImpl implements AProb{
      public void method1(){
         //Some thing
      }
      public void method2(){
         //Some thing
      }
      public void method3(){
         //Some thing
      }
}

public class VerticalPackageSelector extends ScrollView {
   AProb a = new aImpl();
      public void method1(){
         a.method1();
      }
      public void method2(){
         a.method2();
      }
      public void method3(){
         a.method3();
      }
}
```